# Construct String from Array in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I am on Mule 4. I need to create a "filter string" (to be used in an API call) from an array. A sample input array is given below:

```
[
  "123AAA","123BBB","123CCC","123DDD","123EEE"
]
```

I need to get an output string like this using dataweave 2.0
**`ID = '123AAA#DT' OR ID = '123BBB#DT' OR ID = '123CCC#DT' OR ID = '123DDD#DT' OR ID = '123EEE#DT'`**

I tried using joinBy function but since this is in an array, it was giving an error. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a good candidate for [reduce](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-reduce)().

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload reduce ((item, accumulator="") -> "ID = '" ++ item ++ "#DT'" ++ (if (accumulator != "")  " OR " ++ accumulator else "" ))
```